# GitHub claimed to have reach 1.1 Billion contributions. What is a contribution?

Tags: github, statistics, git-commit

[Github latest Octoverse](https://octoverse.github.com/) states

> This year, you're collaborating more than ever before, with 1.1
>   billion contributions—and counting.

Whereas the *Overview* section gives explanation for each word used (eg *Organization*, *Repository*) the term *contribution* is not explained.

Is it a commit? A commit or a pull-request? A modification?

Any idea, with source will be welcome!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks us to speculate about unpublished facts behind an announcement by a private corporation.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub's help site [says that issues, pull requests, and commits are counted as contributions](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#contributions-that-are-counted). The [blog post that originally announced the feature](https://blog.github.com/2013-01-07-introducing-contributions/#contribution-activity) seems to agree.

Comment: Thanks! But your links point to "personal data" ; your own personal contributions. But when analyzing GitHub activity on its own, do you think "contributions" is the sum of all user's contributions? This will eliminate all commits made to a fork repository, all commits that are not is the master branch, and when the contributor's email address is not linked to her GitHub account ; which is a huge number of commits in my opinion.. that's why it surprised me! Do you have any indications of what contributions means when analyzing GitHub as a whole? Thanks again

Comment: Why would GitHub's definition of a "contribution" change when they're considered in the aggregate? It looks like you're really asking about information that GitHub hasn't published publicly, in which case your question is definitely off-topic.